# Setting modal mode to specific screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I'm using stack navigator in my react-native app, i have set the mode to modal so the screen gets pushed from the bottom, it's working fine but is there a way to specify this mode for specific screens only?

```
const App = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
},
{
  mode: 'modal',
 }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

## Solution

Use multiple StackNavigator.

For example, if you want show Modal screen using modal effect only

```js
// Call `this.props.naviation.navigate('Modal') from `Basic` screen, and use 'goBack()' in `Modal` screen.
const ModalStack = createStackNavigator({
  Basic: { screen: Basic },
  Modal: {screen: ModalScreen },
},
{
  mode: 'modal',
 }
);

const Modal = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
  Detail: { screen: ModalStack },
},
);
```